# Is $sl(n,C)$ itself an irreducible representation of $SL(n,C)$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have known that $sl(n,C)$ is a simple Lie algebra and it is a linear representation of $SL(n,C)$ by adjoint.

But is it an irreducible representation of $SL(n,C)$ and is there some relation between this and its property of being simple?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3188894/adjoint-representation-is-irreducible-iff-mathfrakg-is-simple

Comment: That "duplicate" concerns the adjoint representation of the Lie algebra. This question seems to be about a representation of the group. Granted there's a strong connection, but it's not identical in my eyes.

Comment: wsh, can you clarify whether you mean the representation of the group, or its differential for the Lie algebra? We have $ {\displaystyle d_{e}\operatorname {Ad} =\operatorname {ad} } $.

Comment: the representation of the group